# Source for a combo box differs when adding a record

Tags: ms-access-2013

The rowsource for my Sellers combo box (cboSeller) below, currently shows all sellers over several years.  This works ok, but this list is becoming too long and unweildy, so I need to restrict it to only sellers in the current year.

```
    SELECT tblSeller.SellerID, tblSeller.SellerName, tblSeller.sellerCurrent FROM tblSeller ORDER BY tblSeller.SellerName;
```

When adding a new sale, I want to restrict the values in the combo box to only sellers active in the current year.  In tblSeller current sellers are indicated by a "Yes" value in the sellerCurrent field.

When I change the rowsource for the combo box to a query, with the criteria set to "yes" for the  sellers, the cboSeller combo box works and displays only current sellers.

But, when viewing existing sale records, that have a seller from a previous year, do not show the seller in the cboSeller field.

So it seems what I need to do, is when adding a new sale record, change the rowsource for cboSeller to the query with the Yes criteria.  When viewing all sales records, the criteria needs to be removed and revert to showing all sellers.

How do I do this?

Many thanks for any suggestions..  cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the *OnCurrent* event to requery to combobox which will happen if you assign a different rowsource.

```
Private Sub Form_Current

    Const AllSellers As String = <your Select .. for all sellers.>
    Const NewSellers As String = <your Select .. for current only sellers.>

    Dim RowSource As String

    If Me.NewRecord Then
        RowSource = NewSellers
    Else
        RowSource = AllSellers
    End If   
    If Me!cboSellers.RowSource <> RowSource Then
        Me!cboSellers.RowSource = RowSource
    End If       

End Sub
```

Comment: Great. Thanks for the feedback!